# how do i make images blit from the centre when using a camera in pygame?

Tags: python-2.7, camera, pygame

I have an issue I need some help with. When colliding I have an issue, the image is off-centered to the side as when it is blitted it doesn't do it from the centre, so when the sprite collides on one side it goes inwards more than it does on the other side when I just want it to be the same for both sides. It is sort of hard to explain in words. the reason this is an issue and I can't just divide the numbers in the blit command by 2 is because I am using a camera system I found here on stack overflow

this is the key bit in the code that im getting stuck with. I have included all the camera stuff as it may be needed to help

```
       camera.update(player)
        for e in lay3:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))
        # update player, draw everything else
        player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)
        for e in lay2:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))
        for e in lay:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))
        for e in entities:
            if e not in lay and e not in lay2 and e not in lay3:
                screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))        
        pygame.display.update()

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    return Rect(-l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling at the left edge
    l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
    t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top
    return Rect(l, t, w, h)
```

if this is still not enough to solve this is all of the code.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pygame
from pygame import *

WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 640
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)
idlecount = 0
DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
SAI = [pygame.image.load("samusIdle0.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("samusIdle1.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("samusIdle2.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("samusIdle3.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("samusIdle0.png").convert_alpha()]
SAIL = [pygame.image.load("Samus0.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("Samus1.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("Samus2.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("Samus3.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("Samus0.png").convert_alpha()]
def main():
    global cameraX, cameraY
    global bg
    global entities
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()

    up = down = left = right = running = False
    bg = Surface((32,32))
    bg.convert()
    bg.fill(Color("#000000"))
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(32, 32)
    platforms = []

    x = y = 0
    level = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "xg                                                          ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "xf                                                          ij",
        "x                                                           ij",
        "x                                                           Hh",
        "x                                                             ",
        "x                                                             ",
        "x                                                             ",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPV                                        ",
        "KMKMKMKMKMKMKMKMKMKMKQ                      APPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "MKMKMKMKMKMKMKMKMKMKMSPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPZMKMKMKMKMKMKMKMKM",]
    # build the level
    global tile
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                tile = 1
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)

            if col == "A":
                tile = 13
                q = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(q)
                entities.add(q)

            if col == "Z":
                tile = 14
                q = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(q)
                entities.add(q)

            if col == "Q":
                tile = 2
                q = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(q)
                entities.add(q)

            if col == "V":
                tile = 3
                q = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(q)
                entities.add(q)
            if col == "S":
                tile = 4
                q = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(q)
                entities.add(q)
            if col == "K":
                tile = 5
                q = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(q)
                entities.add(q)
            if col == "M":
                tile = 6
                q = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(q)
                entities.add(q)
            if col == "h":
                tile = 7
                q = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(q)
                entities.add(q)
            if col == "H":
                tile = 8
                q = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(q)
                entities.add(q)
            if col == "i":
                tile = 9
                q = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(q)
                entities.add(q)
            if col == "j":
                tile = 10
                q = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(q)
                entities.add(q)
            if col == "x":
                tile = 11
                q = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(q)
                entities.add(q)
            if col == "f":
                tile = 12
                q = Platform(x, y)
                entities.add(q)
            if col == "g":
                tile = 0
                q = Platform(x, y)
                entities.add(q)
                eee = q
                print (entities)
            if col == "E":
                e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                platforms.append(e)
                entities.add(e)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0
    total_level_width  = len(level[0])*32
    total_level_height = len(level)*32
    camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
    entities.add(player)
    global idlecount
    global direction
    direction = 'right'
    while 1:
        timer.tick(60)
        idlecount = idlecount + 0.05
        if direction == 'right':
            player.image = SAIL[int(idlecount)]
        if direction == 'left':
            player.image = SAI[int(idlecount)]
        if idlecount > 4:
                idlecount = 0
        for e in pygame.event.get():

            if e.type == QUIT: raise SystemExit, "QUIT"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                raise SystemExit, "ESCAPE"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True
                down = False
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_DOWN:
                downk = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                direction = 'left'
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True
                direction = 'right'
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                running = True

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
                down = True
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_DOWN:
                downk = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False

        # draw background
        for y in range(32):
            for x in range(32):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        camera.update(player)
        for e in lay3:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))
        # update player, draw everything else
        player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)
        for e in lay2:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))
        for e in lay:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))
        for e in entities:
            if e not in lay and e not in lay2 and e not in lay3:
                screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))        
        pygame.display.update()

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    return Rect(-l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling at the left edge
    l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
    t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top
    return Rect(l, t, w, h)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        global lay
        global lay2
        global lay3
        global idlecount
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,72))
        self.image = SAIL[int(idlecount)]
        lay = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        lay.add(self)
        lay2 = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        lay3 = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 72)

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms):
        if up:
            # only jump if on the ground
            if self.onGround: self.yvel -= 14
        if down:
            self.yvel += 0.5
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
        if not self.onGround:
            # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            down = False
            self.yvel += 0.5
            # max falling speed
            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0
        # increment in x direction
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        # do x-axis collisions
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)
        # increment in y direction
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        # assuming we're in the air
        self.onGround = False;
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                    print "collide right"
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                    print "collide left"
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom
                    down = True
        for q in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                    print "collide right"
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                    print "collide left"
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom


class Platform(Entity):
    global tile
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        if tile == 1:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tile8.png').convert()
        elif tile == 2:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tile7.png').convert()
        elif tile == 3:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tile5.png').convert()
        elif tile == 4:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tile6.png').convert()
        elif tile == 5:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tileA1.png').convert()
        elif tile == 6:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tileA2.png').convert()
        elif tile == 7:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tile10.png').convert()
        elif tile == 8:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tile9.png').convert()
        elif tile == 9:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tile11.png').convert()
        elif tile == 10:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tile12.png').convert()
        elif tile == 11:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tile00.png').convert_alpha()
        elif tile == 0:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('sky.png').convert_alpha()
            lay3.add(self)
        elif tile == 12:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('samusShip.png').convert_alpha()
            lay2.add(self)
        elif tile == 13:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tile13.png').convert()
        elif tile == 14:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('tile14.png').convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image.fill(Color("#0033FF"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thank you for your time,

EDIT:
I should probably mention that the sprites for the player are 52x72 pixels, this creates overhang when touching a wall and I need the overhang to be the same on both sides

Comment: You should try to [minimize](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your code before posting it here. Images can be replaced by `pygame.Surface`s filled with some color `a_surface.fill((100, 120, 140))`. Also, the question is not very clear. Add pictures if it's too difficult to explain something only with words. If I understand you correctly, the problem is that the player overlaps partially with the platforms.

Comment: ok I will try to explain it a bit better. so if you are facing right faces right and if you are facing left the image changes to a left facing one. when it faces right and collides with a block there is some overhang, and that is fine. however when it is facing left and collides there is no overhang because of how it blits. so when it is facing right it looks like this https://postimg.org/image/ppxklnjz5/   but when facing right it looks like this https://postimg.org/image/7p7yknar3/ . im pretty sure this is caused by how it blits but i want the overhang on the first image to happen on the 2nd

Comment: So you actually want the sprite image to overlap with the platforms. Pygame blits the image at the `topleft` coordinates of the sprite's rect, so you maybe need a custom `draw` method for the sprite to add an offset.

Comment: that sounds about right, so how would i go about doing that?

Comment: I'm trying to figure something out, but it's not so easy to combine it with the camera code. I'll update my answer later.

Comment: ok, thank you for your time

Comment: It actually was pretty easy, but the many blitting `for` loops in the `main` function confused me a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the `Player` class a `draw` method in which you add an arbitrary offset to the coordinates.

```
def draw(self, screen, rect):
    x, y = rect.topleft
    screen.blit(self.image, (x-10, y))  # -10 because the rect is 20 px smaller than the image.
```

In the `main` function before `pygame.display.update()` add the line:

```
player.draw(screen, camera.apply(player))
```

Edit: You need to remove the `for e in lay:` loop which blits the player sprite, otherwise it gets blitted twice.

Comment: thank you for your time and help, this was very useful.